# Vue 3 with Tailwind using v-bind:class shows classes in html element but not render while style works correctly

Tags: data-binding, vuejs3

I am new to Vue and I'm trying to bind multiple classes in a v-for loop from a const array of object imported from a file.js.
But the trick I'm trying is to import const and than return classes from method that evaluates one property of object looped.
I've tried all ways, methods, computed, setup, onMounted, beforeMount, but even if i can see my classes in html they aren't rendered in styles section of DevTools.
The only way that works is to v-bind:style instead of class. Or just put exact classes in my const array object as a property but I prefer to avoid this.
It seems to save something in cache, but i have tried to delete and to lunch application in hidden mode but it won't works
Is there someone who can help me to understand and maybe to resolve?
Thanks in advance

```
this is my actual code:

<template>
    <div id="cv" class="tp3-flex md:tp3-grid md:tp3-grid-cols-[repeat(27,_minmax(0,_1fr))] md:tp3-grid-rows-[repeat(6,_minmax(0, 5rem))] tp3-justify-center tp3-content-center tp3-justify-items-center tp3-mx-auto tp3-p-2 tp3-bg-cyan-500 tp3-text-blue-50">

        <div v-for="(softSkill, index) in softSkills" :key="`softSkill-${index}`"
        class="tp3-flex tp3-w-20 tp3-h-20 -tp3-rotate-45 tp3-rounded-full tp3-rounded-tr-none tp3-justify-center tp3-items-center tp3-bg-slate-400 tp3-opacity-70 tp3-mb-4 tp3-mt-4 tp3-shadow-md tp3-overflow-hidden"
        v-bind:class="posCols(softSkill)">
            <div class="tp3-rotate-45">
                <span v-html="softSkill.text"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {softSkills} from "@/assets/skills/softSkills";

export default {
    name: "ComponentSoftSkills",
    data(){
        return{
            softSkills: null
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.softSkills = softSkills;
    },
    methods: {
        posCols(softSkill){
            console.log(softSkill);
            return ' tp3-col-start-['+softSkill.col+'] tp3-col-end-['+(softSkill.col+1)+']';
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>


and my file.js is:

export const softSkills = [
    {text:`skill 1`, col:1, row:1},
    {text:`skill 2`, col:5, row:1},
    {text:`skill 3`, col:2, row:2},
    {text:`skill 4`, col:15, row:1},
]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your returns uses single quotes. Try to have a more appropriate combo with backticks and interpolation so that your strings are dynamically generated as you expect them to be.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it now, but unfortunately the result is the same

Comment: this is how I changed:

            const colEnd = softSkill.col + 1;
            return ` tp3-col-start-[${softSkill.col}] tp3-col-end-[${colEnd}] `;

@kissu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion that this might be due to your tailwind setup.

Because the classes are assigned dynamically and tailwind (depending on the configuration) is only making classes available that it can find during compilation. So the classes, even though you see them populated correctly, are not made available through tailwind. simply put, when tailwind scans the code, it doesn't recognize `md:tp3-grid-cols-[repeat(27,_minmax(0,_1fr))]` or `tp3-col-start-[${softSkill.col}]` as a valid class name and does not generate the class for it.

Assuming this is the issue and not knowing the exact version on configuration can't give an exact solution, but here are some tips for it.

#### Instead of using dynamic class names, define all the class names and assign dynamically

so instead of using `tp3-col-start-[${softSkill.col}] tp3-col-end-[${(softSkill.col+1)}]`

you could make sure all possible classes are clear and accessible by the tailwind parser:

```js
let colClass = `tp3-col-start-[0] tp3-col-end-[1]`;
if(softSkill.col === 1) colClass = "tp3-col-start-[1] tp3-col-end-[2]";
if(softSkill.col === 2) colClass = "tp3-col-start-[2] tp3-col-end-[3]";
if(softSkill.col === 3) colClass = "tp3-col-start-[3] tp3-col-end-[4]";
if(softSkill.col === 4) colClass = "tp3-col-start-[4] tp3-col-end-[5]";
if(softSkill.col === 5) colClass = "tp3-col-start-[5] tp3-col-end-[6]";
// ...etc
```

this is obviously very verbose, but the classes are clearly defined in the code, so tailwind can find them when scanning your code.

#### Safelisting classes

using safelisting of classes is another option. Instead of having the code in your js, you would have it in the configuration

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...other stuff
  safelist: [
    'tp3-col-start-[0]',
    'tp3-col-start-[1]',
    'tp3-col-start-[2]',
    'tp3-col-start-[3]',
    'tp3-col-start-[4]',
    'tp3-col-start-[5]',
    // ...etc
    'tp3-col-end-[1]',
    'tp3-col-end-[2]',
    'tp3-col-end-[3]',
    'tp3-col-end-[4]',
    'tp3-col-end-[5]',
    // ...etc
  ],
}
```

there's also a way to use regex, which might look something like this:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...other stuff
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /tp3-col-start-[(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15)]/,
      variants: ['sm', 'lg'], // you can add variants too
    },
    {
      pattern: /tp3-col-end-[(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16)]/,
    },
  ],
}
```

you can read more about safelisting here [safelisting-classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was going crazy.
Tailwind needs complete class name to compile it and i cannot assign it through js string concatenation. I resolved using 'switch' to evaluate softSkill.col and than returning complete class name